# Real World Need to Minimise Monthly SIM Data Costs

Tags: numerical-methods

This is likely to be a bit basic for you guys but I'm struggling to come up with an automated way to calculate which price plan I should put my SIMs on.

Here's the details:

Plan A costs $1$ per SIM and is only for SIMs that use $<100$ kb of data
Plan B costs $1.70$ per SIM and is for SIMs in a 'Group Plan' that allows $1$ MB of data per SIM (more on how Group Plans work below)
Plan C costs $2.25$ per SIM and is for SIMs in a 'Group Plan' that allows $3$ MB of data per SIM 
Plan D costs $2.83$ per SIM and is for SIMs in a 'Group Plan' that allows $3$ MB of data per SIM 
All of the group plans have an additional charge of $1.70$ per excess MB used

Group Plans allow for SIMs to be placed in a plan and, as long as the total allowance for all of the SIMs is not breached, there are no extra costs e.g. if I had $3$ SIMs in the $1$ MB Group Plan, that group would have a total included allowance of $3$ MB. If one SIM used $1.5$ MB and the other $2$ used $0.7$ MB, I would be charged $3 \times 1.70 = 4.10$ for the $3$ SIMs. If, however, they all used a total of $3.5$ MB, I would be charged $3 \times 1.70$ plus  (excess data) $0.5 \times 1.70 = 4.95$

What I have to work with is a list of $10,000$ SIMs with each SIMs data usage, ranging from $0$ kb to $40$ MB, and I need a formula (that I can use in Excel) that will work out the best way to assign each SIM to a plan to minimise the total cost.

I have been assuming that it's best to have any SIM with $<100$ kb moved straight to Plan A and that I shouldn't allow any excess data charges to occur but I'm not convinced that this is the case.

Any insights on how to automate this to find the lowest total cost would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about you show us what you have attempted so far so that the community can guide you? This is not a place to get answers to your Maths problems :)

Comment: Is there a way to upload a file so that I can show what I've done in excel? Basically, I've been approaching it by trial and error, I've created a tab for each plan and I've just been summing up the data usage on each page and multiplying it by the cost for the plan as well as any excess charges, then summing up the total costs. I've just been moving the items from the total list around the pages, trying to get the total price down. I'm not a sophisticated mathematician, so I can't even think of a formula to work it out automatically - sorry